# How to populate a Grails domain class with a List<Double>

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have to create a Application with Grails 4. For now, there is no database, it's all in memory.

All I want, is that a Module can hold a list of doubles which represent the grades.

The domain class `Module.groovy`:

```
package myapp

import grails.rest.Resource

@Resource(uri='/module', formats = ['json', 'xml'])
class Module {
    String title
    String description
    int semesterID
    List<Double> grades;
    double finalGrade


    static constraints = {
        title blank:false
        description blank:false
        semesterID blank:false
    }
}
```

To develop the app, I'd like to work with a populated object. So I initialize a few in BootStrap.groovy:

```
class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->
        //Create default Modules
        new Module(title: "WebeC", description: "Web Engineering", semesterID: 1).save()
        new Module(title: "WebeC", description: "Web Engineering", semesterID: 2).save()
        new Module(title: "ism", description: "Information Security Management", semesterID: 2).save()
    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

So far so good, but I fail when I try to populate the grades. 
Things I already tried: (all in BootStrap.groovy)

```
//test 1
 new Module(title: "WebeC", description: "Web Engineering", semesterID: 1, grades: [4.0, 5.5, 3]).save()

//test 2
new Module(title: "WebeC", description: "Web Engineering", semesterID: 1, grades: {[4, 5, 6]}).save()

// test 3
 def List<Double> temp = [4.0, 5.5, 3]
 new Module(title: "WebeC", description: "Web Engineering", semesterID: 1, grades: temp).save()
```

The output is always the same:

```
[{"id":1,"title":"WebeC","semesterID":1,"grades":[],"description":"Web Engineering","finalGrade":0.0}, ...]
```

Is it just a syntax problem or is my whole approach wrong? 
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from Andriy Budzinksyy was correct. To work with the REST Api anohter file was missing under views:

```
model{
    Module module
}

json g.render(module, [expand: ['grades'], resolveTemplate: false])
```

I also slightly changed `BootStrap.groovy`:

```
  new Module(title: "WebeC", description: "Web Engineering", semesterID: 1, grades: [4.0, 5.5, 3] ).save(flush: true)
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to add `hasMany` static property in your domain:

```
static hasMany = [grades: Double]
```

And then you should be able to populate the grades with:

```
new Module(title: "WebeC", description: "Web Engineering", semesterID: 1, grades: [4.0, 5.5, 3]).save()
```

In `BootStrap` you have to save domain in the transaction:

```
Module.withTransaction { status ->
     Module module = new Module(name: "name1", grades: [4.0, 5.5, 3])
     module.save(flush: true)
}
```

Comment: That did not work. Still get the same output `[{"id":1,"title":"WebeC","semesterID":1,"grades":[],"description":"Web Engineering","finalGrade":0.0},..]`

Comment: How did you get this json output? I've tested and `module.grades` return proper list, `module as grails.converters.JSON ` as well.

Comment: I got the output via the REST-API `localhost:8080/module`

All other changes I make in the `BootStrap.groovy` file are properly displayed.

Comment: @Geryones, there was a problem with saving the list in non-transaction mode. Check my updated answer.